# Add custom fields / meta data to record in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a basic page model which will usually hold the same sort of data, however occasionally, I might need to add some additional information to a record.

Is there any way to add custom fields / meta data to a record, in the same way that Wordpress allows you to?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the solution that was recently posted on the Laravel forums here: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=12052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use a composer package like this one:

https://packagist.org/packages/navruzm/lmongo

That package is nicely explained on it's Github page [here](http://navruzm.github.io/lmongo/).

Which would allow a MongoDB driver for your Eloquent models. Furthermore, if you develop with `Repository` interfaces/classes (a separation of concerns technique covered nicely [here](http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/) & [here](https://leanpub.com/laravel)) then the aforementioned package would allow you to use MongoDB for your Pages, but not for the other resources in your application.

An example:

- Create a folder `app/src/ExampleAppName/Repository/Page`
- Create a file within that folder `PageRepositoryInterface.php` that looks (roughly) as follows:

  ```
  <?php namespace ExampleAppName\Repository\Page;

  interface PageRepositoryInterface {

      public function all();
      public function find($id);
      public function create($input);
      //... and so on

  }
  ```
- Create another file within the same folder `MongoPageRepository.php` that looks (roughly) as follows:

  ```
  <?php namespace ExampleAppName\Repository\Page;

  class MongoPageRepository implements PageRepositoryInterface {

      protected $mongo;

      public function __construct(LMongo $mongo)
      {
          $this->mongo = $mongo->connection();
      }

      //...Other code ...

      public function create($input)
      {
          //Some kind of validation
          $this->mongo->collection('pages')->insert($input);    
      }

      //...Other code ...

  }
  ```
- You should call `App::bind('PageRepositoryInterface', 'MongoPageRepository');` somewhere (such as `app/start/global.php`) or look into `ServiceProviders` .
- You may then use the Mongo repository from the relevant controller like so:

  ```
  <?php

  class PageController extends \BaseController {

      public function __construct(PageRepositoryInterface $pages)
      {
          $this->pages = $pages;
      }

      //...Other code...

      public function store()
      {
          $input = Input::get();

          $this->pages->create($input);

          //Handle response, etc...
      }

  }
  ```

MongoDB is a "schemaless" database, which would allow you to define additional metadata if you so desired.

**Please** note that this is not a complete answer and you should use it as a guide, rather than a "Copy'n'Paste" solution. I left out vital things (such as error handling, validation and stripping unnecessary fields from `$input`). I advise you have a look at the resources I mentioned or drop by the #laravel channel on IRC.

Comment: Using NoSQL is a big decision, while it might be appropriate for this project it's a bit overkill just to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's too difficult to roll out your own metadata solution. For simplicity sake though, here's a plugin that does it for you:

https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-meta

I don't think it works with arrays though, which I think Wordpress meta does? I'm sure there's a way to though if you create your own system.